# Unable to book a slot in German Consulate

Tags: visas, europe, germany

I have received a job offer from Germany and I have got the contract by FedEx. I wanted to book a slot for document submission in German consulate and there are not slots available till June. I have to start my job on June 1st, 2018. Is there any other way to work around this one? I will be contacting the consulate to hear what they have to say.

I am from India and I would be requiring National VISA FYI.

Thank you!
Vish

Comment: Contact your new employers to advise them of the situation and ask for a later start date?

Comment: Yes I am going to do that on Monday. But is that the only option? Thanks!

Comment: Are there any other German Consulates in India where you could apply? I see there are 5 that do visa processing, are they all fully booked to June?

Comment: Yes but they have divided those 5 consulates to handle few states each. Mine does not have slots available. Thanks!

Comment: @Vish Have you contacted the consulate and explained your situation? They usually give that kind of thing pretty short thrift but you've got nothing to lose. Ask about what happens if someone cancels their appointment.

Comment: @jacoma891 I will be contacting them this Monday. I was completely thrown off as I never realized that the slots would be filled up. Thanks!

Comment: @Vish_evo Have you checked whether the premium service is available? There’s an extra fee of course.

Comment: Even if you had your visa appointment today, it is IMHO completely unrealistic that you would get your visa by June 1st. The official wording from German authorities is that it takes 'several months' to process an application for a national visa and there is no 'express route' for you application.

Comment: Your new employer, if they have recruited from India before, will know it takes a long time. I don't think they will cancel your contract because that would waste the work done in hiring you in the first place.

Comment: @Tor-Einar Jarnbjo: Several months? Good lord. I will be sorting this out on Monday. Thanks for all the replies!

Comment: Just an update. Luckily, someone cancelled an appointment on Monday morning. I booked the appointment on Sunday. Getting the Demand Draft from a bank on a Sunday, getting all the documents ready was such a rush. The interview went smoothly. Hopefully I get the result soon.